# how can i write a groupBy function for list elements in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

It's signature has to look like this:

```
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

My function should group the input list's elements to output lists based on whether the elements are equal or there's a strictly monotonous incrementing partlist in it.

Examples for termination:

```
-- groupBy (==) groups the equal elements
groupBy (==) [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2] == [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
groupBy (==) [0, 1, 2] == [[0], [1], [2]]

-- groupBy (<) returns the strictly monotonous incrementing partlists
groupBy (<) [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3] == [[0,1,2],[1,2,3]]
groupBy (<) [3, 4, 5] == [[3, 4, 5]]

groupBy (>=) [3, 3, 1, 5] == [[3,3,1],[5]] --- monotonous decrementing

-- partlists, where the consecutive elements' difference is 1:
groupBy (\x y -> abs (x - y) == 1) [0, 1, 3, 4] == [[0, 1], [3, 4]]
groupBy (\x y -> abs (x - y) == 1) [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 10, 11] == [[1,2,3,2,1],[10,11]]
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Just write it. Where specifically are you stuck at?

Comment: dont even know where to start, but its an assignment for tomorrow :(

Comment: There are many good Haskell tutorials available online; feel free to consult one to get some ideas about where to start, and come back when you have a concrete problem with code you have written. As for the other half of your comment... my band teacher in high school had a note on his door: "Poor planning on your part does not constitute an emergency on my part.". Internalizing that changed my life, and I hope you find it as helpful as I did (though it does suck to hear it during your first poor planning emergency).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comparisons that have to happen here. You're providing a function `f :: a -> a -> Bool` that will group each item as long as it remains true, in other words:

```
groupBy (>=) [3, 3, 1, 5, 4]
                [3]
3 >= 3 = True   [3, 3]  -- add RHS value
3 >= 1 = True   [3, 3, 1]
1 >= 5 = False  -- new group!

                [5]
5 >= 4 = True   [5, 4]
```

This looks like recursion to me. Your inner function should keep an accumulator, look at each element of the list and decide to either A) include it in the current accumulator or B) give the accumulator back and start a new one based on the results of `f`.

It's probably helpful to define `groupBy` as a wrapper around some helper function that does the real work.

```
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy f (x:xs) = go f [x] xs
  where
  -- base case: no values left to check
  go _ acc       [] = [acc]

  -- recursive case
  go f acc@(y:_) (x:xs)
    | y `f` x   =  go f (x:acc) xs    -- add to current group
    | otherwise =  acc : go f [x] xs  -- start a new group
```

Note that the above has a subtle bug that I left in for illustrative purposes (and also because I wrote it this way first, so you might, too!)